# How to logically justify the rejection of null hypothesis?

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, random, hypothesis-testing

The rejection of null hypothesis will be valid only if this is true:
If the probability of the obtained result given that an assumption is true is very low, then the probability that the assumption is true is very low.

But I have seen no logical justification for this fact.

(Note that saying that the p-value shows the likelihood of the null hypothesis being right is a fallacy. ([Link](https://www.graphpad.com/support/faq/common-misunderstandings-about-p-values/)) P value doesn't deal with probability of the assumption at all.)

I have seen justifications based on intuition such as: we intuitively reject the assumption that the experiment is random, if we obtain 100 heads in 100 coin tosses. But this doesn't logically show that the assumption being true is a low probability case (which it should in order to come to the conclusion).

So what is the logical justification for that?

Comment: Philosophically, the kind of things we apply statistics to are the kind of things we cannot prove logically -- even with evidence. So, strictly speaking, there is never a logical justification, and there never could be a logical justification. Even if you could directly show that the assumption has low probability, that would not be a logical proof that the assumption is false. Instead, we make the best inference we can.